# Catching errors in godot 4, gdscript

Tags: gdscript

I need to encode this opening file and read it:

```
var file = FileAccess.open('res://file.save', FileAccess.READ)
print(file.get_var())
```

It works quite well, but if I delete the `file.save` file, an error occurs.

Is there anything similar to `try` / `except` from Python in Godot 4 (GDScript)? How can I handle errors?

Answer (score 1):

If the file failed to open, the `open` method will return `null`, so you check like this:

```
var file := FileAccess.open('res://file.save', FileAccess.READ)
if file == null:
    prints("some error happened while opening the file")
else:
    print(file.get_var())
```

---

No, there isn't `try-catch` in GDScript. Instead it uses return values. Often failure is expressed with `null` (the case above) or with an error code (see [Error](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_%40globalscope.html#enum-globalscope-error)).

---

**Addendum**

Checking if a file exists before opening it is usually a [time-of-check to time-of-use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use) vulnerability. That is, somebody might remove the file just after your code checked but before it was opened causing unexpected behavior on your program.

With that said, this being resource paths, that shouldn't happen in release as they are read only (see [resource path](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/filesystem.html#resource-path)), because they map to the contents of a pck file or equivalent.

Which also means you should NOT use resource path for your save files.

*The situations might still be relevant for a game running from the editor, or in the editor (ì.e. a `@tool` script), because during development the resource paths point to actual files.*

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Theraot's answer, you could use `FileAccess`'s `file_exists()` method to check if the file exists...

```
if (FileAccess.file_exists('res://file.save')):
    var file = FileAccess.open('res://file.save', FileAccess.READ)
    print(file.get_var())
else:
    print("Save file does not exist.")
```

> Is there anything similar to try / except from Python in Godot 4 (GDScript)?

Currently, Godot 4.2 does **not** support error handling and have previously stated that they have [no plans to add it](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/3516#issuecomment-177152034).

However, with the updates to GDScript there is still a chance that it will be implemented. If you want more information on the topic you can check out [this discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/godotengine/godot-proposals/discussions/4736).